# Can we efficiently pull objects out of an array in cython?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, cython

I've timed the following sample code with cProfile, and these were the results.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    3.283    3.283    3.283    3.283 {comparison.addition_with_arrayview}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {comparison.simple_addition}
```

With the help of others, I've managed to get cython near C speeds using objects, structs, and other methods, but I can't find a way to deal with an array of objects.

Is there a way to further reduce the python overhead incurred when pulling an object out of an array in cython? (I've used cdef as much as I know how.)

Sample Code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cdef class AdditionClass:
    cdef long int value

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    cpdef int add_one(self):
        self.value += 1
        return 0

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

cdef:
    int loops = 10
    long int a_big_number = pow(10, 7)

def simple_addition():
    cdef long int value = 0

    for i in range(loops):
        for ii in range(a_big_number):
            for iii in range(10):
                value += 1
        print "Loop ", i, " out of ", loops, '. Value: ', value
    return None

def addition_with_arrayview():
    cdef AdditionClass addInstance
    cdef long int value = 0

    addition_classes = np.array([None] * 10)
    for i in range(len(addition_classes)):
        addition_classes[i] = AdditionClass(0)

    cdef AdditionClass[:] arrayview = addition_classes

    for i in range(loops):
        for ii in range(a_big_number):
            for iii in range(10):
                addInstance = arrayview[iii]
                addInstance.add_one()

        print "Loop ", i, " our of ", loops, '. Value: ', \
            arrayview[i].get_value(), " split between 10 arrays."

    return None
```

Profile script:

```
import cProfile
import comparison

def calling_all():
    comparison.simple_addition()
    comparison.addition_with_arrayview()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cProfile.run('calling_all()', sort='time')
```

Thank you very much for your time and any advise!

Comment: Great question but I think it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've been playing with this further... the reasoning for 0.000s with simple addition is due to the compiler simplifying the +1 addition. I'm going to rewrite this question a little better, making use of a chaos addition function that can't be simplified, and compare it with with a C++ module for meaningful timers. I'll post the new question in code review like you suggested!

Comment: As I said before, great question, I wish we had more questions of this quality! And good luck at codereview!